# Computing a nested sum in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and to python so I want to ask you guys a simple way to compute a double sigma by programming

(∑<sup>n</sup><sub>i=1</sub>)(∑<sup>m</sup><sub>k=1</sub>)(i+k)

I am trying to solve the problem but I'm stuck on the part where I need to initialize p any Hints will be appericiated.

here is what I tried so far

```
p = 1
sum = 0

N,M=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(1,N+1):
    for i in range(i+1,i+M+1):
        p=p*i
    sum += p

print(sum)
```

Comment: Can you give expected input and output samples?

Comment: I wanted to learn the concept behind the double summation. The original question is on [link](https://www.codechef.com/LOCMAY18/problems/DSERIES)

Comment: @UtkarshKulshrestha the link you've posted is not related to "double summation" as is your code (i.e. your code doesn't not calculate the mathematical expression you've posted).

Comment: Sorry I already knew that I just don't want the answer to that question as it will be morally wrong to make someone else solve competitive programming questions for me. That is why  I changed the question BUT forgot to change my code accordingly .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following:

[image]

This means your naïve quadratic O(m*n) algorithm can be replaced with a linear O(m+n) solution:

```
In [1]: from hypothesis import strategies as st
   ...: from hypothesis import given, settings
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: def linear(n, m):
   ...:     return n * sum(range(1, m+1)) + m * sum(range(1, n+1))
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: def quadratic(n, m):
   ...:     total = 0
   ...:     for i in range(1, n+1):
   ...:         for j in range(1, m+1):
   ...:             total += i + j
   ...:     return total
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: @given(st.integers(1, 50), st.integers(1, 50))
   ...: @settings(max_examples=1000)
   ...: def test(n, m):
   ...:     assert linear(n, m) == quadratic(n, m)
   ...: 
   ...:     

In [2]: test()

In [3]: %timeit linear(10, 10)
852 ns ± 15.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit quadratic(10, 10)
7.93 µs ± 165 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Since you are a beginner, I've added a simple automatic property test to: 1) emphasise the importance of testing a working naïve solution vs an optimised alternative, 2) demonstrate the equivalence. A couple of benchmarks for small `n` and `m` are also there.

And since there is a closed-form equation for sums of arithmetic series (i.e. *M* and *N*), you can further boil this down to a constant time O(1) solution (I've done a fair bit of simplification here):

```
In [5]: def constant(n, m):
   ...:     return n * m * (2 + m + n) / 2
   ...: 
   ...: 

In [6]: %timeit constant(10, 10)
151 ns ± 1.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

P.S.

You should never shadow a built-in name (e.g. `sum = 0`) in the global name-space without a very good reason for that.

Comment: Opps I almost forgot the P.S. point ill keep that in mind. I'll keep that linear solution in mind.

Comment: @UtkarshKulshrestha you should be using the constant-time solution instead. This whole process was just an illustration.

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach (not runtime optimized), you need to reset your `p` variable denoting your *inner product* in each run of your sum; thus set it to `1` at the beginning of each *outer loop*:

```
sum = 0

N,M=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in range(1,N+1):
    p = 1
    for i in range(i+1,i+M+1):
        p=p*i
    sum += p

print(sum)
```

With this approach and the domains given in your exercise, you will not be able to compute it for higher numbers in the given time constraint. You may want to optimize this.

Comment: I didn't want to get an answer to the original question so I posted a different equation and forgot to update my code accordingly .Silly me my mistake

Comment: Edited accordingly.